# Pass more than one command line argument to kdb

Tags: cmd, kdb

I am trying to call a q instance with a `.q` script, a port and a timer from a `.CMD` file:

```
q.exe code.q -p 9001 -t 10000
```

It fails on `-t`

If I do it this way I get the timer and port set but not the `.q` script:

```
q.exe -t 10000 code.q -p 9001
```

Tried other switched and tried with square brackets, but I am never able to have it use those 3 arguments.

Is there a specific order?

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs, the first arg after the q binary/executable must be a script, database or file (or none). A script, database or file can't be in any other position unless you're simply passing it in as a custom arg to be parsed manually (i.e. it won't auto-run/load). https://code.kx.com/q/basics/cmdline/

Your first attempt should have worked.....what was the error?

Comment: No error really. It just crashes. It I remove the -t the script works fine. Any way I could pass in the -t inside of code.q maybe ?

Comment: It's possible that your timer function `.z.ts` (if you have one defined) is causing the crash, not the fact that you've set `-t`. And yes, you can set the timer within the script using `system"t 10000";`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is exactly what is happening.